# Crawl speed slowdown on large site crawl

Tags: web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a large website (about 1.5 mio url's) using the screaming frog spider tool. Everything is working nice and fast at ~30 pages/second at the beginning (using 20 threads), but it slows down gradually to a crawl speed of 2 pages/second after around 300k to 400k crawled pages.

My first thought was that i caused the server to slow down, but restarting the crawl would make the crawler run fast again.

I tried multiple configurations in database storage mode with 2 to 12 gb alocated ram. I changed between several user-agents (screaming-frog, google-bot, firefox browser etc.) and header options.

Also, increasing or decreasing the threads wouldn't make any difference in the total crawl speed either. The response times of each page would adjust accordingly to be at 2 pages/second in total, meaning that the more threads I used, the slower each response would have got.

I would appreciate any insights on this matter.

Comment: This is most likely a protection built-into the website.

Comment: @RobertBaron Are there any quick work arounds? Also, the website I'm crawling is my company's, but I would like to avoid knocking on different doors on this.

Comment: Do they have a [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) file that provides url's that are to be used specifically by robots? Sometimes these url's point to xml files that contain all the data you may want. Other than that, you could restart you process regularly, to continue the crawl.